# undefined method `likes?' for #<User:0x007fa57a66ba80>

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been installed acts_as_votable gem for my web application. I have separate button for like and unlike. then i want to merge them to be more beautiful. So i create an if condition

```
<% if current_user.likes? post %>
                    <td>
                        <%= link_to 'unlike', {:controller => 'post', :id => post , :action =>'unlike'}, class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger" %>  
                  </td>
                    <% else %>
                  <td>
                     <%= link_to 'like', {:controller => 'post', :id => post , :action =>'like'}, class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger" %>  
                  </td>
                  <% end %>
```

and this give me an error

but in my rails console is working:

[image: 1]

Comment: Did you restart the rails server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable), it's `liked?` not `likes?`:

```
<% if current_user.liked? post %>
```

Comment: Did you restart the rails server?

Comment: how can i commend you?

Comment: click on the check mark to mark it as the correct answer

Comment: i didn't restart rails server i just copy your codes thanks tokland